# Outgoing connections in ping and aptitude not working

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, debian, ping

My Server is setup with Debian 9.2.
When I try to do a ping to any server using a domain, I get no answer.
I noticed that error because aptitude is not updateing and installing. The same with some other outgoing traffic. As soon as I use the ip address instead, everything is working.
Example: `traceroute google.com` is working, `ping google.com` is not.
I've got no more idears what the problem might be.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you run a tracert on the aptude servers and see what it returns? Also, do you have a firewall filter on your network?

Comment: Hi Elliot, I already disabled the firewall. As I just found out ipv4, aptitude, ... are trying to connect via the AAAA record. I forced the usage of ipv4 by adding the currently needed entries to the /etc/hosts. I actually don't know why ping (ipv4) tries to send to ipv6 but I'll just setup ipv6 now

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure out what was going wrong. If you could please write up your finding you as an answer that would be awesome!

Comment: I'm voting to delete this question as the author answered it themselves but didn't provide a solution